# How to convert curl POST with headers authorization and form to PowerShell v3.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have follwoing curl command which I would like to convert to PowerShell (PowerShell v3.0):

```
curl -s -k -H 'Authorization: api_key 1234567890' -F upload_file=@"C:\path\to\file" -X POST "https://my.url.com/submit"
```

What I have so far:

```
$Body= @{ "upload_file" = "C:\path\to\file" };
$Headers = @{ "Authorization" = "api_key 1234567890" };
$Uri = "https://my.url.com/submit"

Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $Uri -H $Headers -Body $Body
```

I think the form parameter is the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $Uri -H $Headers -InFile "C:\path\to\file" -ContentType 'multipart/form-data'` - can you try this and let me know if it works?

Comment: I switched to Invoke-RestMethod because it's a REST API with JSON data as response. I got an error: "Found malformed parameters". I think we need to provide the field name "upload_file".